# Several plotsomposes in one figure (Plot)

Tags: matlab, som

I've created network for function prediction. There are several neurons, each represents own function piece.

Is there a way to display each piece in one **figure(in subplots)**?

I know, that **plotsompos** do it for one neuron, but it makes big graphic, 
so I can't do this every time for each of 10-20 neurons.
Can I build **graphics** on

```
net.weights{}
```

by myself for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want several plots in single plot you can try **Subplot** function

For example here 4 subplots are plotted in single window with x against y1,y2,y3,y4:

```
x = linspace(-5,5);
y1 = sin(x);
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(x,y1)
title('First subplot')

y2 = sin(2*x);
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(x,y2)
title('Second subplot')

y3 = sin(4*x);
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(x,y3)
title('Third subplot')

y4 = sin(6*x);
subplot(2,2,4)
plot(x,y4)
title('Fourth subplot')
```

Comment: Try to do it with plotsompos function, this isn't working.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what exactly you are trying and what is not working? May be with some more information :)